# how to read an xml file and display graph on eclipse using JFreechart

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

> Element not recognised: catagoryDataset

this is what I am getting everytime I am trying to read an xml file and trying to display a bar chart..same for the other charts..I am using JFreeChart..but the problem is even though the graph is being diplayed..there is no plotting

[image] ..please help

Comment: Please provide an example of your code :)

Comment: the question is read user specified datafile for rainfall/month.Ask user for his preferred graph and draw the graph.The graphs to display are bar graph a pie chart a frequency polygon etc.